# Move a div if the height of another div is greater than value (with jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

See the image below. This illustrates what I am trying to achieve. I am sure it is possible with jquery but do not have the expertise to write it.

What i want is that if 'DIV A'(shown in green) has a height lower than a set PX value (for example if div A's height is smaller than 300px) then 'DIV B' (shown in red) should move the the second position. If DIV A's height is greater then that value then DIV A should simply remain in place and not be moved.

[image: What i want to achieve]

I started a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qwcpokdL/

example code:
    
    
    
    B

```
<div class="right">
<div class="B">A</div>   
</div>
```

example css:

```
.left, .right {width:49%; border: 1px solid #000; margin:1px; min-height:600px}
.left {float:left;}
.right {float:right;}
.somediv, .somediv2 {width:98%; height:125px; border:1px solid #ccc; margin:2px}

.A {background:red; width:98%%; height:150px; margin:2px}
.B {background:green; width:98%; height:100px; margin:2px}
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: create an empty container div under "A" `<div id="container_for_b"></div>` then when your page has loaded, get the `A` height, and if height is smaller than 300px then copy the B div's contents to the empty container and then delete the original B.

Comment: The question you wrote is really helpful to share. So, I translated it to share with Korean developers [here](http://ctrlaltdel.co.kr/). If you mind it, please let me know and it will be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  if($('#A').height() < 300){
    $('#A').remove().appendTo("#right");  
  }
});
```

Take a look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/banhjx1x/1/

Comment: I assigned ids in my jsfiddle example so it is #A. Please check the link I shared.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divAheight = $('.B').height();
    if(divAheight >= 100) {
        $( ".A" ).insertAfter( ".B" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQuery:

```
function checkA(){
    if($('.B').height()<300){
        var a = $('.A');
        $('.A').remove();
        $('.B').after (a);
    }
    else {
        var a = $('.A');
        $('.A').remove();
        $('.right').append(a);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkA();
});
$( window ).resize(function() {
    checkA();
});
```

Also don't forget to add script tag for jQuery in your code.